# How to get Ionic working behind a proxy? (Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com github.com:443)

Tags: github, ionic-framework, proxy, ionic2, ionic3

I have failed to create an `Ionic` project using the `Ionic CLI`. Each time I type 
`Ionic start project-name` 
gives me this error :

```
Fetching app base (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.tar.gz)
✖ Downloading - failed!
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com github.com:443
```

Note that, I am working behind a `proxy`. `npm`, `git` proxies are properly set (atleast I think so) and I can create `angular-cli` projects without any problem.

Please help me configure proxies properly for Ionic setup. I'm on `Windows 7 x64`.

[image]

Comment: internet connection is must for creating application in ionic.

Comment: @varunaaruru Ofcourse I have internet connection

Comment: can you try clearing the npm cache and try ionic start again

Comment: hi. could you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the same issue have been raised in github . You can confirm the issue there [Ionic 3 CLI unable to start project behind proxy](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/2317)

Comment: Done. i hope they will look into it.